# Use Asynctask for multiple Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, fragment

I have 2x fragment java classes, which needs to use the same asynctask. Are there anyway i can do this, or do i have to copy/paste the same asynctask in both fragment classes? i have these 3 java classes in total:

- MainActivity
- dataTabelFragment
- sensorOverviewFragment

The asynctask is fetching data from json URL.

Maybe it's possible to make another java class for the asynctask?

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What you say suggest you should decouple your async task code from both fragments and instead have separate worker (perhaps `IntenstService` would server you well here instead) that you fragments would call to have the job done. Or, depending on your code structure (you should think of this if you haven't yet :) maybe your async task code should be part of you fragments' base class that both of them would then extend.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your fragments are in same `Activity` (MainActivity), so you can put your `AsyncTask` in your `MainActivity.class` and your fragments can communicate with your `Activity` with listener. Something like this:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment{

    private YourListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            mListener = (YourListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement YourFragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    interface OnSearchFilterListener {

        void onItemClick(int position);

    }   

}
```